# Combining two pandas columns with based on values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join

I have some data that I'm trying to merge based on values. Over time the naming convention changed and a "0" was added into the column names which resulted in two columns capturing the same data; example:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'MSG235': [1,0,1,0,0], 'MSG0235': [0,0,0,1,1]})

df4

MSG0235  MSG235
   0       1 
   0       0 
   0       1 
   1       0 
   1       0
```

How would I combine these columns in a way that if either (or both) equal 1, the result would be 1, and if both and only both were 0, the result would be 0?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
 MSG235
   1 
   0 
   1 
   1 
   1
```

I've tried:

```
df4.rename(columns = {'MSG0235': 'MSG235'}, inplace = True)

def col_join(x): 
    return ''.join(x[x.notnull()].astype(str))

df4.groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).apply(lambda x: x.apply(col_join, axis = 1))
```

Which results in:

```
MSG235
  01 
  00 
  01 
  10 
  10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
df4['MSG235'] = (df4.any(1) == 1).astype(int)
df4.drop('MSG0235', axis = 1, inplace = True)

    MSG235
0   1
1   0
2   1
3   1
4   1
```

Comment: `df4.any(1).astype(int)` should work also. Or get dataframe, `df4.any(1).astype(int).to_frame(name='MSG235')`

Comment: @Vaishali I left out that I have more than just two columns. This works great though :) The only change I made was `df4['MSG235'] = (df4[['MSG0235', 'MSG235']].any(1) == 1).astype(int)` so that I could confine `.any(1)` to specific columns. Thanks for the help!